# Not able to connect to specific schema of aws postgres using spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have created an specific schema(example myschema) in aws postgre service and I am trying to connect with my spring boot application. But It is not working. I am successfully able to connect to public schema for aws postgre, but not able to connect with new schema created.
I have tried using below two method:

1. Appending schema in jdbc url:  jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxxxxx/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
   But in here my application is performing CRUD in public schema.
2. I tried to add below two properties in application.properties ,

spring.datasource.hikari.schema=myschema AND
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=myschema

since I am using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate, property, while starting spring application it is getting failed and showing error like "org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table"
but the table and required objects created.

Kindly suggest me related to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. using of **default_schema** in application properties

   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: my_custom_schema
2. explicitly specifying schema **for each entity**

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "my_table", schema = "my_custom_schema")

You don't need to patch jdbc url in any way.
I use hikari but I've never specified spring.datasource.hikari.schema. It looks redundant

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the answer, I have tried the first option, its was not working, but I will try 2nd option. Also, is this issue might be related to java version? I am currently using Java 11.